# What patterns exist for web application development?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I understand that MVC & MVP are design patterns that are commonly used for web development, as well as ASP.NET WebForms (more of an anti-pattern, really!).

What other patterns are used in web application development? I'm not necessarily saying I want to learn/use new patterns just to be different - I do believe there's a lot of value in taking the conventional route - but I think it's good to know what else is out there to be able to properly understand what I'm currently working with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Martin Fowler's ["Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are interested in something new, look at the [DCI architecture](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html)